# Extract columns of numpy array consisting of lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a variable `var`

When I print it in jupyter, it gives:

```
var

#array([list([9166855000000.0, 13353516.0]),
#       list([7818836000000.0, 11389833.0]),
#       list([20269756000000.0, 29527304.0]),
#       list([66886956000000.0, 97435384.0]),
#       list([58686560000000.0, 85489730.0]),
#       list([50809440000000.0, 74014984.0])], dtype=object)
```

or

```
print(var)

[list([9166855000000.0, 13353516.0]) 
 list([7818836000000.0, 11389833.0])
 list([20269756000000.0, 29527304.0])
 list([66886956000000.0, 97435384.0]) 
 list([58686560000000.0, 85489730.0])
 list([50809440000000.0, 74014984.0])]
```

The type is:

```
print(type(var))

#<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

How can I devide the second elements of the sublists by the first ones?

I want to get the following values as an array or list:

```
13353516.0/9166855000000.0
...
74014984.0/50809440000000.0
```

Comment: The 1d object dtype array is effectively a list of lists.  If the lists are all the same length you could use `np.stack(var)` (or `vstack`) to make a 2d array.  Otherwise you'll need to use a list comprehension to iterate through the lists, and select the desired value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I generate the structure like this:

```
import numpy as np

var = np.empty([6,], dtype=object)

ll = [list([9166855000000.0, 13353516.0]),
       list([7818836000000.0, 11389833.0]),
       list([20269756000000.0, 29527304.0]),
       list([66886956000000.0, 97435384.0]),
       list([58686560000000.0, 85489730.0]),
       list([50809440000000.0, 74014984.0])]

for i, l in enumerate(ll):
    var[i] = l
```

then `var` contains a 1D array (of lists)

```
array([list([9166855000000.0, 13353516.0]),
       list([7818836000000.0, 11389833.0]),
       list([20269756000000.0, 29527304.0]),
       list([66886956000000.0, 97435384.0]),
       list([58686560000000.0, 85489730.0]),
       list([50809440000000.0, 74014984.0])], dtype=object)
```

and the solution might be:

```
[var[i][1] / var[i][0] for i in range(len(var))]
```

returning a list:

```
[1.4567172710815215e-06,
 1.4567172146851526e-06,
 1.4567172885554222e-06,
 1.456717270853229e-06,
 1.4567173472086283e-06,
 1.4567171769655403e-06]
```

Or, indeed, a more elegant solution would be using @hpaulj's suggestion and @DmitriChubarov's solution:

```
var = np.stack(var)

var[:,1] / var[:,0]
```

returning an array:

```
array([1.45671727e-06, 1.45671721e-06, 1.45671729e-06, 1.45671727e-06,
       1.45671735e-06, 1.45671718e-06])
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be rather straightforward

```py
var[:,1] / var[:,0]
```

would output

```
array([1.4567172710815215e-06, 1.4567172146851526e-06,
       1.4567172885554222e-06, 1.456717270853229e-06,
       1.4567173472086283e-06, 1.4567171769655403e-06], dtype=object)
```

To reproduce define `var` as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
var = np.array([list([9166855000000.0, 13353516.0]),
       list([7818836000000.0, 11389833.0]),
       list([20269756000000.0, 29527304.0]),
       list([66886956000000.0, 97435384.0]),
       list([58686560000000.0, 85489730.0]),
       list([50809440000000.0, 74014984.0])], dtype=object)
```

Comment: J don't think yiu `var` duplicates his.  His is 1d, your's 2d

Comment: Hello Dima indeed in your example `var` is  2d. And when I print your `var` with `print(var)` it is different as given in my question:  `[[9166855000000.0 13353516.0]
 [7818836000000.0 11389833.0]
 [20269756000000.0 29527304.0]
 [66886956000000.0 97435384.0]
 [58686560000000.0 85489730.0]
 [50809440000000.0 74014984.0]]`. `print(np.shape(var))` is for your `var` `(6, 2)` and in my case  I get `print(np.shape(var))` `(6,)`.

Comment: @len could you provide an example that generates a structure of shape `(6,)` as you are having?